# How to send validation error message to view with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

currently adding validations to my project, and i came across Fluent Validation, and i created my validator like this:

```
using Dealership.App.Models.CarBrand;
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dealership.App.FluentValidation
{
    public class CarBrandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateCarBrandViewModel>
    {
        public CarBrandValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(brand => brand.CarBrandName).NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Car Brand needs to have a name");
        }
    }
}
```

And as the docs suggest, i configured it in the Startup file like this:

```
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

And now here is my action method in the controller on which i am applying my validation

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost(CreateCarBrandViewModel newBrand) 
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new CreateCarBrandCommand(newBrand));
        if (response)
        {
            this._unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model Dealership.App.Models.CarBrand.CreateCarBrandViewModel

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
<form asp-action="CreatePost" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BrandName">Brand Name</label>
        <input asp-for="CarBrandName" class="form-control col-4" id="BrandName" placeholder="Enter Car Brand name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CarBrandName"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Here is the thing, my validation works 50%, what i mean is that the validation works on the aspect if the field i specified in the validator is null, it will redirect back again to the same page, that all fine.
But i wanted to show the error message i set up in the validator, i already tried many stuff and read many stuff, would be amazing if anyone could help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the view?

Comment: i can indeed, see above

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found the answer, it was a simple RedirecToAction, because i need to go back to the create view when the validation fails.
Intialially i had `return RedirectToAction({view-name})`, and i needed to do
`return View({view-name})`.